# The File.delete() method doesn't work.. can you mabye help me?

Tags: java, java-io

I wanted to make this password changer, where one first makes a new file, then puts the data in the original file in a string[] array and changes the password in the array. Then I want to delete te original file (this doesn't work) and at last put the data in the new file and rename it to the name of the original. but it won't delete the original, do you maybe know what I am doing wrong?

```
 public static void wijzigenWachtwoordMainAccount(String pad, Integer nr)  throws IOException{
        wijzigdeel2(wijzigendeel1(pad, nr), pad, nr);
    }

    public static String[] wijzigendeel1(String pad, Integer nr) throws IOException{
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String naam = list.get(nr).name;
        String geb = list.get(nr).Gnaam;
        String[] geg; geg = new String[20];
        System.out.println(naam+", voer hier het nieuwe wachtwoord in:\n");
        String newww0 = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Voer het nieuwe wachtwoord opnieuw in:");
        String newww1 = s.nextLine();

        if (newww0.equals(newww1)) {
            File old = new File(pad + "\\Account\\" + geb + "\\" + geb + ".txt");
            File nieuw = new File(pad + "\\Account\\" + geb + "\\" + naam + ".txt");
            if (nieuw.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Succes");
                String info = "";
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(old));
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    info = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    geg[i] = info;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                geg[3] = newww0;
                return geg;

            } else System.out.println("Error...");
        } else System.out.println("Error....");

        return geg;
    }
    public static void wijzigdeel2(String[] gegevens, String pad, Integer nr) throws  IOException{
        String geb = list.get(nr).Gnaam;
        String naam = list.get(nr).name;
        File oud = new File(pad+"\\Account\\"+geb+"\\"+geb+".txt");
        File nieuw = new File(pad+"\\Account\\"+geb+"\\"+naam+".txt");
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(nieuw);
        if (oud.delete()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                f.write(gegevens[i]+"\n");
            }
            f.close();
            if (nieuw.renameTo(oud)) {
                System.out.println("Alles is netjes gewijzigd");

            } else System.out.println("Error.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Fout");
    }
```

Comment: Too much code! :-) If this is only about deleting a file, it should be 1 or 3 lines max. Can you bring this down to a [mcve]? Also, include what OS you're on, and double check the file permissions for the user running the program. See also [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The `java.io.File` API is old and has a number of issues due to the API design and its various implementations.  In this case, if a file deletion fails the `File.delete` method cannot tell you why.

I recommend that you change your code to use the newer `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.Files` APIs which were introduced in Java 1.7.  For example:

> `java.nio.file.Files`
>
> `public static void delete(Path path) throws IOException`
>
> Deletes a file.
>
> An implementation may require to examine the file to determine if the file is a directory. Consequently this method may not be atomic with respect to other file system operations. If the file is a symbolic link then the symbolic link itself, not the final target of the link, is deleted.
>
> If the file is a directory then the directory must be empty. In some implementations a directory has entries for special files or links that are created when the directory is created. In such implementations a directory is considered empty when only the special entries exist. This method can be used with the `walkFileTree` method to delete a directory and all entries in the directory, or an entire file-tree where required.
>
> On some operating systems it may not be possible to remove a file when it is open and in use by this Java virtual machine or other programs.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `path` - the path to the file to delete
>
> Throws:
>
> - `NoSuchFileException` - if the file does not exist (optional specific exception)
> - `DirectoryNotEmptyException` - if the file is a directory and could not otherwise be deleted because the directory is not empty (optional specific exception)
> - `IOException` - if an I/O error occurs
> - `SecurityException` - In the case of the default provider, and a security manager is installed, the SecurityManager.checkDelete(String) method is invoked to check delete access to the file

---

We cannot say for sure why the `File.delete` is failing.  But if you use `Files.delete` instead you should get an exception, and the exception message should make the cause of the problem clearer.

(FWIW, if you are using Windows, my guess is that the file is locked by your own application or some other application.  That would cause delete to fail.  This is a Windows-specific issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have the file open and in use and currently bound to another process somewhere else, likely within your own application, and therefore can not delete the file. How is `list` filled? Better yet...what is `list` and **what** is filling it?

If I were you I wouldn't bang my head to much by creating a temporary file for this sort of thing. Just re-write the existing data file, after all, you place everything into a String Array (**geg[]**) anyways. You even change the necessary element within that array and then write it to a new file. Why not just overwrite the original file? You're basically just doing the same thing anyways except it's a long winded way of doing it.

The current code concept you're using right now basically worked for me but then again I didn't do it exactly the same way....I shortened it up somewhat since I didn't have access to the `list` collection and actual data. Never the less it does do what you want.

As mentioned earlier, I wouldn't do it this way. If you want to change the password in a specific data file, then do just that. It not like changing data in a text file is the same as changing data in a typical database. To change the data in a text file, you need to re-write the entire text file. For small amounts of data this is no big deal but for larger amounts of data, a database starts to look real appealing. Pretty much as easy to work with code-wise and much more flexible.

In any case, the code below basically does what your code does with the exception that it doesn't create and delete files. It merely overwrites the original data file. You supply the data file path and file name, the Old password, and the New password. The new password is applied to the data file and it doesn't matter how many different accounts are in the data file, all passwords that match the supplied Old Password with be changed to the New Password. This in itself can be troublesome in data files that contain several accounts since some people can use the same password (all the more reason to hash passwords based on a specific seed). It's a good idea to add additional criteria to which password you want to really change like perhaps an Account Number or at the very least, a User Name but that's beyond the scope of this particular post:

```
public static void changePassword(String dataFilePath, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
    ArrayList<String> modList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Create a File object
    File dataFile = new File(dataFilePath);

    // Does the file exist?
    if (!dataFile.exists()) {
        // No - Inform and get outta here!
        System.err.println("File Not Found Error!! (" + dataFilePath + ")");
        return;
    }

    // File exists so...Get Old Password:
    String info = "";
    // 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close the reader.
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile))) {
        while ((info = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (info.equals(oldPassword)) {
                info = newPassword;
            }
            modList.add(info);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    String[] geg = modList.toArray(new String[0]);

    // Re-write data file with new Password.
    // 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close writer.
    try (FileWriter f = new FileWriter(dataFile)) {
        for (String dataString : geg) {
            f.write(dataString + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.println("Password Successfuly Changed!");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```